# Увеличение дискогово пространства для DB Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle, oracle11g, resize

Есть DB Oracle 11g  Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit, размер DB составляет 690GB (зарезервировано 700 по DB). Руководство не хочет удалять логи сжимать DB и т.д.
Принято решение добавить дисковое пространство на сервер Windows (увеличили на 50GB пока, ждем диски).
При увеличение пространства Windows-  reserved не изменилось, как было 700 так и осталось

```
Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   703201,467 662728,717   40472,75
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как указать Oracle что зарезервированное пространво увеличилось на 50 Gb (пока) после расширения диска на Windows серврере.
Я начал "копать" в сторону tablespace_name. Вот запрос и вывод:
tablespace_name есть на данный момент (цифры в Gb)

```
SQL> SELECT USED.TABLESPACE_NAME, USED.USED_BYTES AS "USED SPACE(IN GB)", FREE.FREE_BYTES AS "FREE SPACE(IN GB)" FROM (SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS USED_BYTES FROM USER_SEGMENTS GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME) USED INNER JOIN (SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME,TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(BYTES,0))/1024/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS FREE_BYTES FROM USER_FREE_SPACE GROUP BY TABLESPACE_NAME) FREE ON (USED.TABLESPACE_NAME = FREE.TABLESPACE_NAME);

TABLESPACE_NAME                USED SPACE(IN  FREE SPACE(IN
------------------------------ -------------- --------------
SYSAUX                                   0.56           0.11
UNDOTBS1                                 0.32          11.64
SYSTEM                                   0.71           0.00
```

И c него я понямаю что tablespace SYSTEM нужно увеличивать.
по синтаксису это делается командой

```
ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM RESIZE 1G;
```

Только мене еще не совсем понятно если я укажу RESIZE 1G у меня в итоге станет 1G или 1.7G.
И вызывает сомнение этот вывод:

```
TABLESPACE_NAME                USED SPACE(IN  FREE SPACE(IN
------------------------------ -------------- --------------
SYSAUX                                   0.56           0.11
UNDOTBS1                                 0.32          11.64
SYSTEM                                   0.71           0.00
```

И очень похоже на то что у меня есть сейчас с размером базы
при таком запросе

```
SQL> select "Reserved (MB)", "Reserved (MB)" - "Free (MB)" "Used (MB)","Free (MB)" from( select (select sum(bytes/(1014*1024)) from dba_data_files) "Reserved (MB)", (select sum(bytes/(1024*1024)) from dba_free_space) "Free (MB)" from dual );

Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   703201,467 663063,905 40137,5625
```

Может  все таки при вывел значение SYSTEM в Tb, тогда все логично, увеличиваем размер SYSTEM на
ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM RESIZE 0.05G (или 0.76G еще не понятно это добавление к существующему заначению или установка нового)
в итоге получает 750GB.
Подскажите пожалуйста, я прав в своих  рассуждениях? или подскажите как грубо говоря как дать понять oracle, что ему еще добавли 50 gb дискового пространства?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы датафайл добавили в табличное пространство? Оракл видит только то место, которое под него выделили.

Comment: Нет, датафайл я не добавлял. Я новичек в Oracle. Подскажите как его добавить.

Comment: Я знаю почему нет места, а вот как добавить, уже не помню. Могу порекомендовать [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670517/how-to-add-the-datafile-to-tablespace-which-is-already-full](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43670517/how-to-add-the-datafile-to-tablespace-which-is-already-full) ну или поищите по примерному запросу: _oracle add datafile to tablespace_

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, спасибо.
Что необходимо было сделать:
1)Проверяем текщее занятое пространство

```
SQL> select "Reserved (MB)", "Reserved (MB)" - "Free (MB)" "Used (MB)","Free (MB)" from( select (select sum(bytes/(1014*1024)) from dba_data_files) "Reserved (MB)", (select sum(bytes/(1024*1024)) from dba_free_space) "Free (MB)" from dual );

Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   3582,99014 1028,80264  2554,1875
```

Проверяем какое тип файлов используется (SMALLFILE или BIGFILE)

```
SQL> SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, CONTENTS, BIGFILE FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;

TABLESPACE_NAME                CONTENTS  BIG
------------------------------ --------- ---
SYSTEM                         PERMANENT NO
SYSAUX                         PERMANENT NO
UNDOTBS1                       UNDO      NO
TEMP                           TEMPORARY NO
USERS                          PERMANENT NO
```

Из проверки видим что используется SMALLFILE
Для SMALL используем команду

```
SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE USERS ADD DATAFILE '/oraclexe/app/oracle/oradata/XE/users01.dbf' SIZE 2G AUTOEXTEND ON;
```

Команда создает файл BD users01.dbf по пути к общей папке БД и тем самым увеличивает объем свободного пространства на 2G.
Проверяем увелилось ли пространство
Добавляем:

```
SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE USERS ADD DATAFILE '/oraclexe/app/oracle/oradata/XE/users02.dbf' SIZE 1G AUTOEXTEND ON;
Tablespace altered.
```

Проверяем:

```
SQL> select "Reserved (MB)", "Reserved (MB)" - "Free (MB)" "Used (MB)","Free (MB)" from( select (select sum(bytes/(1014*1024)) from dba_data_files) "Reserved (MB)", (select sum(bytes/(1024*1024)) from dba_free_space) "Free (MB)" from dual );

Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   4617,08876 1039,90126  3577,1875
```

Если используется BIGFILE
Для тестирования специально создаю BIGFILE

```
 SQL> CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE SYSTEM01 DATAFILE '/oraclexe/app/oracle/oradata/XE/SYSTEM01.dbf' SIZE 5G;
```

Проверяю что он создался и действительно BIGFILE

```
SQL> SELECT TABLESPACE_NAME, CONTENTS, BIGFILE FROM DBA_TABLESPACES;

TABLESPACE_NAME                CONTENTS  BIG
------------------------------ --------- ---
SYSTEM                         PERMANENT NO
SYSAUX                         PERMANENT NO
UNDOTBS1                       UNDO      NO
TEMP                           TEMPORARY NO
USERS                          PERMANENT NO
SYSTEM01                       PERMANENT YES
```

При создании такого файла пространство сразу увеличтся

```
SQL> select "Reserved (MB)", "Reserved (MB)" - "Free (MB)" "Used (MB)","Free (MB)" from( select (select sum(bytes/(1014*1024)) from dba_data_files) "Reserved (MB)", (select sum(bytes/(1024*1024)) from dba_free_space) "Free (MB)" from dual );

Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   9787,58185 1091,39435  8696,1875
```

Увеличиваю пространство для BIGFILE ДО!!!! 7GB

```
SQL> ALTER TABLESPACE SYSTEM01 RESIZE 7G;
Tablespace altered.
```

Результат + 2GB к свободному пространству

```
SQL> select "Reserved (MB)", "Reserved (MB)" - "Free (MB)" "Used (MB)","Free (MB)" from( select (select sum(bytes/(1014*1024)) from dba_data_files) "Reserved (MB)", (select sum(bytes/(1024*1024)) from dba_free_space) "Free (MB)" from dual );

Reserved (MB)  Used (MB)  Free (MB)
------------- ---------- ----------
   11855,7791 1111,59159 10744,1875
```

Если база данных расположена на другом диске (например диск G:/) ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО указать полный путь к БД

```
SQL> CREATE BIGFILE TABLESPACE SYSTEM01 DATAFILE 'G:/oraclexe/app/oracle/oradata/XE/SYSTEM01.dbf' SIZE 5G;
```